# polymer expressions access property by its name

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

trying to render a table as a polymer element

```dart
      <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
               <th template repeat='{{ column in columns}}'>
                  {{column.displayName}}
               </th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr template repeat='{{ row in data}}'>
               <td template repeat='{{ column in columns}}'>
                 {{row[column.name]}}
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
```

the following expression doesn't seem to work as i expected

```dart
{{row[column.name]}}
```

column.name is the property name that i want to access in the row object but it gives the following exception for all properties

```dart
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: '[]'
Receiver: Instance of 'Product'
Arguments: ["id"]
```

is this the right way to access a property by name?

my row model looks like this

```dart
class Product extends Observable{
  int id;
  String name;
  String category;
}
```

One work around which i don't like is overloading the [] in the row class

```dart
operator [](String fieldName){
    var im = reflect(this);
    return im.getField(new Symbol(fieldName)).reflectee;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if 'row' is a map.

Comment: but what if i don't want to use a map? no work around?

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how your row looks like? You can implement the '[] ' operator in your row.

Comment: i though about overriding the [] in my row class, but i didn't try yet, so its not possible directly from polymer expressions to access the properties dynamically?

Comment: No, this is not supported.